# Prepared statements in C++ libneo4j_client?

Tags: c++, libneo4j-client

The [neo4j_run API](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/latest/neo4j-client_8h.html#ae975ef8a6ba72d3cc98dfcc7b96f4f30) allows you to enter a map, but I don't know the syntax of the query.  In python, this is a simple `{x}`.  I cannot find an example of the `neo4j_map` syntax.

```
const char *q = "MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.age > {age} RETURN p.name AS name, p.age as AGE";
neo4j_run(session, q, my_map)
```

How should I (a) construct `my_map` and (b) indicate the fields in the query?

UPDATE: For the first part, [this test](https://github.com/cleishm/libneo4j-client/blob/master/tests/check_values.c#L385-L394) shows how to construct the map.  Copied here for clarity:

```
START_TEST (invalid_map_value)
{
    neo4j_map_entry_t map_entries[] =
        { { .key = neo4j_string("bernie"), .value = neo4j_int(1) },
          { .key = neo4j_int(1), .value = neo4j_int(2) } };
    neo4j_value_t value = neo4j_map(map_entries, 2);
    ck_assert(neo4j_is_null(value));
    ck_assert_int_eq(errno, NEO4J_INVALID_MAP_KEY_TYPE);
}
END_TEST
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map passed as the third argument to `neo4j_run` is the parameters for the query. Constructing the map takes an array of entries and its length. If it's just a single entry map, you could pass a pointer to a single `neo4j_map_entry_t`. For your example:

```
const char *q = "MATCH (p:Person) WHERE p.age > {age} RETURN p.name AS name, p.age as AGE";
neo4j_map_entry_t map_entry = neo4j_map_entry("age", 28);
neo4j_value_t params = neo4j_map(&map_entry, 1);

neo4j_run(session, q, params);
```

If there are multiple parameters, build an array of map entries, e.g.:

```
const char *q = "MATCH (p:Person) WHERE {min_age} < p.age < {max_age} RETURN p.name AS name, p.age as AGE";
neo4j_map_entry_t map_entries[2];
map_entries[0] = neo4j_map_entry("min_age", 28);
map_entries[1] = neo4j_map_entry("max_age", 30);
neo4j_value_t params = neo4j_map(map_entries, 2);

neo4j_run(session, q, params);
```

You can also build the map_entry_t using an initializer, as in the example test you copied. But it's usually clearer to use the [`neo4j_map_entry`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/latest/neo4j-client_8h.html#a9c83a47ac2e9b17bbd5b25c516e6c039) constructor.

Comment: Is there an easy way to send in a string array.  For instance if the query includes `WHERE p.name IN ["Brian", "Chris"]` ?  I cannot find something like a `neo4j_string_array` type.

Comment: I had two problems with this.  (a) I had to wrap the integer with `neo4j_map_entry("min_age", neo4j_int(28))` and (b) when trying to use a string like `neo4j_map_entry("name", "brian")` or `neo4j_map_entry("name", neo4j_string("brian"))` I got "no matching call for strlen".  Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey @BrianDolan - I'm unsure why you'd get that. `neo4j_string(s)` is macro that expands to `neo4j_ustring((s), strlen(s))`. But `strlen` is defined in `string.h`, which is included by `neo4j-client.h`. Perhaps you can supply the code, and we can try to reproduce?

Comment: @BrianDolan, you can use [`neo4j_list`](https://cleishm.github.io/libneo4j-client/doc/latest/neo4j-client_8h.html#a93b3e42c87b79fa751c2e85ab0375634) for building a string array.

Comment: I found an example in [your github](https://github.com/cleishm/libneo4j-client/blob/master/tests/check_values.c#L259-L313)

Comment: Another thing to note, the replacement is viewed as an array, you can do to `WHERE IN {ids}` not, for instance `WHERE IN [{ids}]`. That wasn't clear to me.